# Using Protractor to change the boolean value of a variable in $scope

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angularjs-scope

I'm using Protractor + Selenium to automate some integration tests for my angularjs web app. One of my DOM elements has an `ng-if` directive like so:

```
<button ng-if="browserSupported">
```

When running my tests, I've found that `browserSupported` is set to false and the button is not in the DOM. Is there any way to change `browserSupported` to be true using Protractor? I want to test some functionality after clicking that button (it's supposed to open up a new tab with a specific URL.)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I'm using Selenium WebDriver Standalone version 2.53, which is using Firefox version 46. I think when the selenium test runs, that version of firefox causes `browserSupported` to be false and the button is not in the DOM

Comment: I don't have a solution, but an idea where to look. If you can access that variable from browser's console then you can inject a script that will be executed in the scope of browser by `await browser.executeScript();`